# Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "" because "this.serviceBol" is null en Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-tool-suite

Estoy tratando de actualizar un campo en String en la base de datos de Boleta de un registro existente, Cuando uno se genera el archivo XML y obtengo el hash. No se actualiza a la boleta registrada en el campo hashcode. Me aparece Nulo cuando utilizo @Autowired. En esta parte es la clase de BoletaRepository donde hago llamar actualizarHashCode en el siguiente Codigo:

BoletaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface BoletaRepository extends SearchRepository<Boleta, Long> {

    public Long countById(Long id);

    @Query("SELECT MAX(numeroBoleta) FROM Boleta")
    public Integer obtenerUltimoNumeroSerieBoleta();

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Boleta c WHERE c.numeroBoleta LIKE %?1%")
    @Override
    public Page<Boleta> findAll(String keyword, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("UPDATE Boleta c SET c.enabled = ?2 WHERE c.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    public void updateBoletaEnabledStatus(Long id, boolean enabled);

    @Query("UPDATE Boleta c SET c.hashcodeticketBoleta = ?2 WHERE c.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    public void actualizarHashCodeBoleta(Long id, String hashcodeticketBoleta);

    @Query("UPDATE Boleta c SET c.pendienteticketBoleta = ?2 WHERE c.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    public void actualizarEstadoBoleta(Long id, String pendienteticketBoleta);
}
```

En la clase de BoletaService es donde obtengo la inyeccion de la boletaRepository

BoletaService

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class BoletaService {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BoletaService.class.getName());

    public static final int BOLETAS_PER_PAGE = 15;

    @Autowired
    private BoletaRepository boletaRepo;

    public Boleta saveBoleta(Boleta boleta) {
        return boletaRepo.save(boleta);
    }

    public void actualizarHashCodeBoleta(Long id, String hashcodeticketBoleta) {
        boletaRepo.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(id, hashcodeticketBoleta);
    }

    public void actualizarEstadoBoleta(Long id, String estadoBoleta) {
        boletaRepo.actualizarEstadoBoleta(id, estadoBoleta);
    }
    
    public Boleta get(Long id) throws BoletaNotFoundException {
        try {
            return boletaRepo.findById(id).get();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            throw new BoletaNotFoundException("NO ENCONTRAMOS BOLETA CON ESTE NUMERO " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

En esta clase LecturaXML es independiente para poder inyectar a la clase de BoletaService, Tener en cuenta que la boleta electronica o factura electronica tiene sus clases como BoletaRepository, BoletaService, BoletaController, Dentro de la BoletaController llamo para a la clase para generar el archivo XML, dentro de la clase de generar el archivo XML, hay sintaxis que llamo a la LecturaXML

LecturaXML

```
@Component
public class LecturaXML {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LecturaXML.class);

    @Autowired
    private BoletaService serviceBoleta;
    
    private String codehash;
    private String estado;

    public String getCodehash() {
        return codehash;
    }

    public void setCodehash(String codehash) {
        this.codehash = codehash;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getRespuestaSunat(String path) {
        String respuesta = null;
        String nota = null;

        try {
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - iniciamos Lectura del contenido del CDR " + path);
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();

            //Obtener la lista de nodos que tienen etiqueta "ds:Reference"
            NodeList responsecode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode");
            for (int i = 0; i < responsecode.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = responsecode.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList nodesc = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Description");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesc.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = nodesc.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = respuesta + "|" + datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList note = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Note");
            for (int i = 0; i < note.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = note.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                nota = nota + datoContenido.getNodeValue() + "\\n";
            }

            String[] cdr = respuesta.split("\\|", 0);
            //=== Guardar el link
            if (cdr[0].equals("0")) {
                this.setEstado("A");
            }
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR Observacion: " + Arrays.toString(cdr).trim());
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR Observacion: " + nota);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR codigo: " + cdr[0]);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR Nota: " + cdr[1]);

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXException - El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: IOException - Error al leer el archivo de respuesta : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: ParserConfigurationException - ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (DOMException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: DOMException : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo para obtener Respuesta Sunat con ticket
     *
     * @param path
     * @return respuesta
     */
    public String getRespuestaSunatTicketfe(String path) {
        String respuesta = null;
        String nota = "";

        try {
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - iniciamos Lectura del contenido del CDR " + path);
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();
            //Obtener la lista de nodos que tienen etiqueta "ds:Reference"
            NodeList responsecode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode");
            for (int i = 0; i < responsecode.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = responsecode.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList nodesc = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Description");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesc.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = nodesc.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = respuesta + "|" + datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList note = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Note");
            for (int i = 0; i < note.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = note.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                nota = nota + datoContenido.getNodeValue() + "\\n";
            }

            String[] cdr = respuesta.split("\\|", 0);
            //=== Guardar el link
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaTicketSunatTicket - resultado del CDR Observacion: " + nota);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaTicketSunatTicket - resultado del CDR codigo: " + cdr[0]);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaTicketSunatTicket - resultado del CDR Nota: " + cdr[1]);
        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXException - El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: IOException - Error al leer el archivo de respuesta : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: ParserConfigurationException - ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (DOMException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: DOMException : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } finally {

        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    public void guardarHashYBarCodePDF417(String tipoDoc, String trans, String accion, String pathXMLFile) {

        try {
            String hashCode = obtenerDigestValue(pathXMLFile);
            /*============ALMACENANDO  BarcodePDF417(codigo de Barra)=========*/
            BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
            String infobarcode = tipoDoc.equals("20") ? getInfoToBarCodeOD(pathXMLFile) : getInfoToBarCode(pathXMLFile);
            infobarcode = infobarcode.replaceAll("\n", "");
            log.info("==>infoBarcode:" + infobarcode);
            barcode.setCode(infobarcode);
            java.awt.Image img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
            BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            outImage.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(outImage, "png", bytesOut);
            bytesOut.flush();
            byte[] pngImageData = bytesOut.toByteArray();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngImageData);
            log.info("LecturaXML.obtenerDigestValue BarCodePDF417 - resultado HashCode : " + hashCode);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("==>Error en generación de hash o barCode:" + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public void guardarHashYBarCodeQR(String tipoDoc, String numeroDocu, String pathXMLFile, Boleta boleta) {
        try {
            String hashCode = obtenerDigestValue(pathXMLFile);
            this.codehash = hashCode;
            /*============ALMACENANDO  BarcodePDF417(codigo de Barra)=========*/
            //QRCodeWriter barcode = new QRCodeWriter();
            String infobarcode = tipoDoc.equals("20") ? getInfoToBarCodeOD(pathXMLFile) : getInfoToBarCode(pathXMLFile);
            infobarcode = infobarcode.replaceAll("\n", "");
            log.info("==>infoBarcode:" + infobarcode);
            QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(infobarcode, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 350, 350);

            Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(pathXMLFile.replace("xml", "png"));
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);

            ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
            byte[] pngImageData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngImageData);
            log.info("LecturaXML.obtenerDigestValue BarCodeQR - resultado HashCode : " + hashCode);
            log.info("LecturaXML Guardando HashCode en la Boleta : " + this.codehash);
            System.out.println("Estado de la Boleta : " + this.getEstado());
            serviceBoleta.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(boleta.getId(), this.codehash);
        } catch (WriterException | IOException ex) {
            log.error("==>Error en generación de hash o barCode:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String obtenerDigestValue(String path) {
        String firma = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();
            //Obtener la lista de nodos que tienen etiqueta "ds:Reference"
            NodeList listaEmpleados = raiz.getElementsByTagName("ds:Reference");
            //Recorrer la lista de empleados
            for (int i = 0; i < listaEmpleados.getLength(); i++) {
                //Obtener de la lista un empleado tras otro
                Node empleado = listaEmpleados.item(i);
                //Obtener la lista de los datos que contiene ese ds:Reference
                NodeList datosEmpleado = empleado.getChildNodes();
                //Recorrer la lista de los datos que contiene el ds:Reference
                for (int j = 0; j < datosEmpleado.getLength(); j++) {
                    //Obtener de la lista de datos un dato tras otro
                    Node dato = datosEmpleado.item(j);
                    //Comprobar que el dato se trata de un nodo de tipo Element
                    if (dato.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        //Mostrar el nombre del tipo de dato
                        if (dato.getNodeName() == "ds:DigestValue") {
                            //El valor está contenido en un hijo del nodo Element
                            Node datoContenido = dato.getFirstChild();
                            //Mostrar el valor contenido en el nodo que debe ser de tipo Text
                            if (datoContenido != null && datoContenido.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                                //System.out.println(datoContenido.getNodeValue());
                                if (datoContenido.getNodeValue() != null) {
                                    firma = datoContenido.getNodeValue();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: Se ha producido un error al leer el fichero\n" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return firma;
    }

    public String getInfoToBarCode(String path) {
        String respuesta = "";
        try {
            String IssueDate = "";
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();

            //=====RUC
            NodeList nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:PartyIdentification");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";

            //=====InvoiceTypeCode
            NodeList InvoiceTypeCode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode").item(0) == null ? raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode") : raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode");
            respuesta += InvoiceTypeCode.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";
            //=====cbc:ID
            nodlist = raiz.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:ID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent().replaceAll("-", "|") + "|";
                }
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:IssueDate")) {
                    IssueDate = nod.getTextContent();
                }
            }
            //=====>LegalMonetaryTotal

            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:LegalMonetaryTotal").item(0) == null ? raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:RequestedMonetaryTotal").item(0).getChildNodes() : raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:LegalMonetaryTotal").item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount")) { //NO EN : ND
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:PayableAmount")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }
            //=====>IssueDate
            respuesta += IssueDate + "|";
            log.info(respuesta);

            //=====>AccountingCustomerParty
            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:AccountingCustomerParty").item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:AdditionalAccountID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:org.xml.sax.SAXException - ERROR: Al leer el archivo de respuesta" + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:Error IOException - ERROR: Al leer el archivo de respuesta" + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:Error ParserConfigurationException - ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n" + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (DOMException exg) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:Error DOMException - ERROR: Al leer el archivo de respuesta" + path + "en getInfoToBarCode" + exg.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    public String getInfoToBarCodeOD(String path) {
        String respuesta = "";
        try {
            String IssueDate = "";
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();

            //=====RUC
            NodeList nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:PartyIdentification");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";

            //=====InvoiceTypeCode
            //NodeList InvoiceTypeCode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode").item(0) == null ? raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode") : raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode");
            respuesta += "20" + "|";//InvoiceTypeCode.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";
            //=====cbc:ID
            nodlist = raiz.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:ID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent().replaceAll("-", "|") + "|";
                }
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:IssueDate")) {
                    IssueDate = nod.getTextContent();
                }
            }
            //=====>LegalMonetaryTotal

            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:TotalInvoiceAmount");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";

            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("sac:SUNATTotalPaid");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";
            //=====>IssueDate
            respuesta += IssueDate + "|";

            //=====>AccountingCustomerParty
            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:ReceiverParty").item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cac:PartyIdentification")) {
                    NodeList noi = nod.getChildNodes();
                    for (int x = 0; x < noi.getLength(); x++) {
                        Node nodx = noi.item(x);
                        if (nodx.getNodeName().equals("cbc:ID")) {

                            respuesta += nodx.getAttributes().getNamedItem("schemeID").getTextContent() + "|";
                            respuesta += nodx.getTextContent() + "|";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n" + ex.getMessage());
            respuesta = "Error al leer el archivo de respuesta";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al leer el archivo de respuesta\n" + ex.getMessage());
            respuesta = "Error al leer el archivo de respuesta";
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n" + ex.getMessage());
            respuesta = "Error al leer el archivo de respuesta";
        } catch (DOMException exg) {
            System.out.println("==>Error while reading file " + path + " on getInfoToBarCode(path)\n");
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
}
```

Este es el error que obtengo como Nulo en el ServiceBoleta incluido con @Autowired, y no lo inyecta.

```
2023-09-10T16:32:12.240-05:00  INFO 36024 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] p.com.carbonstar.admin.util.LecturaXML   : LecturaXML.obtenerDigestValue BarCodeQR - resultado HashCode : MTIpa+f0o7DYKtZebc7jJOviqjc=
2023-09-10T16:32:12.240-05:00  INFO 36024 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] p.com.carbonstar.admin.util.LecturaXML   : LecturaXML Guardando HashCode en la Boleta : MTIpa+f0o7DYKtZebc7jJOviqjc=
Estado de la Boleta : null
2023-09-10T16:32:12.243-05:00 ERROR 36024 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/admin] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pe.com.carbonstar.admin.boleta.BoletaService.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(java.lang.Long, String)" because "this.serviceBoleta" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pe.com.carbonstar.admin.boleta.BoletaService.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(java.lang.Long, String)" because "this.serviceBoleta" is null
    at pe.com.carbonstar.admin.util.LecturaXML.guardarHashYBarCodeQR(LecturaXML.java:231) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.com.carbonstar.admin.cpews.BolElectronica.generarXMLZipiadoBoleta(BolElectronica.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.com.carbonstar.admin.boleta.BoletaController.generarBoletaElectronica(BoletaController.java:620) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Buenas, Croelan, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes indicar qué version de spring estás usando? ¿Has probado a quitar la anotación @Configurable de la clase BoletaService? Por lo que he leido rápidamente, dicha anotación se usa cuando se quieren inyectar dependencias que no son gestionadas por spring. En tu caso, el repositorio sí es generado por spring, con lo cual no deberías necesitarla.

Comment: Hola @RubioRic, Gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy usando Spring 3.1.3, Ya he probado en quitar la anotación, igual me sale error. Lo que sucede que la clase LecturaXML tiene una instancia en la BolElectronica.java es decir LecturaXML lectura = new LecturaXML(). Ahora bien, lo que hice es hacer un codigo en la clase de BoletaController, ahi empezo a actualizar los datos que necesito. Ni modo, queria hacerlo desde la clase LecturaXML sin tocar la clase BoletaController. De todos modos, agradezco tu respuesta.

Comment: ¿En BolElectronica eres tú el que instancia explicitamente LecturaXML en lugar de dejar que lo haga spring? Ahí está el problema entonces, cuando tú haces new LecturaXML() nadie establece el valor serviceBoleta. A priori deberías poner otro @Autowired en ese lectura que tienes en BolElectronica. Por otro lado me parece raro que LecturaXML deba tener un campo serviceBoleta. El modelo clásico de capas iría así: Controller llama a Service, Service llama a clase de Utilidad [LecturaXML], dependiendo de lo que devuelva Utilidad, Service actualiza lo que sea y devuelve un resultado al Controller.